# Ansible win_shell ad-hoc syntax

Tags: windows, ansible, yaml, jinja2

I'm trying to run the win_shell Ansible module as an ad-hoc command with the "anisble" program instead of in a playbook.  Here is the playbook syntax:

```
  tasks:
      - win_shell: foo.exe
        args:
              chdir: 'C:\bar'
              executable: cmd
```

I've tried various permutations such as:

```
ansible \* -i windows.inventory -k -m win_shell -a "foo" -a "executable=cmd"
ansible \* -i windows.inventory -k -m win_shell -a "foo" -a "args: executable=cmd"
ansible \* -i windows.inventory -k -m win_shell -a "foo" -a "args=executable: cmd"
ansible \* -i windows.inventory -k -m win_shell -a "foo" -a "args=(executable=cmd)"
ansible \* -i windows.inventory -k -m win_shell -a "foo" -a "args={{arg}}" -e '{arg: {executable: cmd} {chdir: "C:\\bar"}}'
ansible \* -i windows.inventory -k -m win_shell -a "foo" -a "args={{arg}}" -e '{arg: {executable: cmd},{chdir: "C:\\bar"}}'
ansible \* -i windows.inventory -k -m win_shell -a "foo" -a "args={{arg}}" -e '{"arg": {"executable": "cmd"},{"chdir": "C:\\bar"}}'
ansible \* -i windows.inventory -k -m win_shell -a "foo" -a "args={{arg}}" -e '{"arg": {"executable": "cmd"},{"chdir": "C:\\bar"}}'
ansible \* -i windows.inventory -k -m win_shell -a "foo" -a "args={{arg}}" -e '{"arg": {"executable": "cmd"}}'
```

None of these work.

I can do it this way:

```
ansible \* -i windows.inventory -k -m win_shell -a 'cmd /c "cd C:\bar & foo"'
```

...but I want to know how to do it by specify the "args".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Ansible inline syntax and a single `-a` argument, without split.

Here's how the task translates to the CLI arguments:

```
ansible \* -i windows.inventory -k -m win_shell -a 'foo.exe chdir=C:\bar executable=cmd'
```